# "tests are skipped" message in Maven Thucydides Framework using JUnit

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, thucydides

When I exceute my testcase in command prompt(-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false) "Tests are skipped" message is displaying.  Some one please help me to sort this issue.

POM - maven-surefire-plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<systemProperties>
<property>
<name>testSuite</name>
<value>${testSuite}</value>
</property>
</systemProperties>
<skip>true</skip>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please post the POM or relevant sections from it. You most likely have instructed the `surefire` plugin to skip the tests.

Comment: You explicitly have `<skip>true</skip>` in your pom.xml.  third line from last in what you posted.

Comment: I set <skip>false</skip> and even i tried without <skip>, It's not working @JohnAment